# Logrus: How to print con console log

Tags: go, logging

Implementing Logrus Go package. File is saved but stopped printing out on the console the logs only visible in created .log file called vendor.log.

Here is the code currently using.

```
package logging

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    mylog "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

// InitializeLogging asdas
func InitializeLogging(logFile string) {

    var file, err = os.OpenFile(logFile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could Not Open Log File : " + err.Error())
    }
    mylog.SetOutput(file)

    //log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{})
    mylog.SetFormatter(&mylog.JSONFormatter{})
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try writing to multiple targets:

```
mylog.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(file, os.Stdout))
```

Comment: You are right, I was actually reading about this. Thanks. There is now a strange behavior and it's that it outputs JSON and not the nice formatted colored console log. any Ideas? @bserdar

Comment: You commented out the text formatter and set up the JSON formatter instead, that's why it is printing out JSON logs. It is the SetFormatter function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use logrus you should better use hooks which is recommanded by documentation.

See : https://github.com/rifflock/lfshook for examples.

Using multiwriter is not optimal, because you can't have a different formatting for stdout and file, what you generally want to (colors for stdout and different timestamp for file for example).